# In rust, what's a good way to ask for input when there exists a default value, and empty input should be possible?

Tags: input, terminal, rust, stdin

I want to ask for user input, and the user should also be able to specify an empty value, and should also be able to just use the default value.

```
Enter a value ("default"):
```

The above has an issue if pressing enter is to give the default value `default`: how will the user specify an empty string as the input?

Some ideas I have are showing the default input and allowing the user to backspace it if they want to, or using a keyboard shortcut to use the default value. Of these two, I think the first would be better, but I don't know great ways to implement it. I tried a couple of crates to at least implement the second, like [crossterm-input](https://crates.io/crates/crossterm_input) and [signal-hook](https://crates.io/crates/signal-hook), but I wasn't able to do it.

With `crossterm-input`, I tried something like this:

```
let mut use_default = false;
if let Ok(_raw) = RawScreen::into_raw_mode() {
    let input = input();
    let mut stdin = input.read_sync();

    if let Some(key_event) = stdin.next() {
        match key_event {
            InputEvent::Keyboard(k) => match k {
                KeyEvent::Ctrl(c) => match c {
                    if c == 'y' {
                        // use the default value
                        use_default = true;
                    }
                },
                _ => {},
            },
            _ => {},
        };
    }
}
```

and this did recognize ctrl + y properly, but as it goes into raw mode, other key presses are also ignored until `_raw` goes out of scope.
With `signal-hook`, I tried something like this:

```
let signals = Signals::new(&[SIGINT]).unwrap();

let mut use_default = false;
thread::spawn(move || {
    for sig in signals.forever() {
        println!("Received signal {:?}", sig);
        use_default = true;
    }
});
```

but this only recognized ctrl + c, and I guess that's because only `SIGINT` was in the array given to `Signals::new()`. Then, I realized that `signal-hook` only seems to support recognizing signals the terminal handles by default.

So what's a good way to get the functionality I want?

Comment: As always it's good to show the solution you tried but you ask a XY problem, please show the code of the real problem instead of showing the code of the problem you have trying to fix your first problem. Currently your question is very confuse.

Comment: @Stargateur I don't really _have_ code for the real problem; I just have a problem, and code for the solutions I tried... Please tell me what else I should include!

Comment: Your question conflicts with itself.  How does a user indicate to use the default value while also being able to submit an empty value?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 in the example solution I gave, where the default value is there but the user can backspace it to submit an empty value, this will work. Why does it conflict itself? In any one case, the user only submits an empty value, or the default value, or a different custom value.

Comment: @Cubetastic What's the purpose of having an empty value while also being able to submit the default value by keybind?  This is the reference to "XY Problem" above.

Comment: Using a keyboard shortcut or rebinding a signal (SIGINT, in this case) is a terrible idea on its own. Consider just letting the person enter an empty value and, if possible, consider that as "I didn't want anything, let me pick the default". Most prompts actually do that

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, @SébastienRenauld, there is definitely a purpose to being able to submit an empty value as well as a default value. For example, if the input was used to create a config file, the default value could be `do action a`, while an empty value could be `don't do anything`. Or, if they were used to edit a field, then the default value could leave it as it is, and an empty field could delete the existing value

Comment: in that case I'd consider escape or refining your prompt so this is never an issue (split it in two - do anything? if so what?)